# set folder read only to false

Tags: c#

Currently my code to set the folder read only to **false**.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\NightlyBuild");
            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

However, I did this to find the file in smallest file by sorting them in decesending order:

```
string path = "C:\\NightlyBuild\\";
var files = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "NightlyBuild.*");
            foreach(var file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(int.Parse(args[0])))
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(int.Parse(args[0])))
            Directory.Delete(file, true);
```

Any way to alter this code so that whatever file that i delete?
I just want to set that file read-only to false? This file is actually a folder fyi

Comment: do you want to delete a file but before deleting you want to set it's ReadOnly attribute to false?

Comment: That doesnt make sense, why would you want to make it read only, to then immediately delete it?

Comment: @BugFinder no.. i am trying to set the read-only to false.. ie remove Read-Only property. so that i can delete the files

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
File.SetAttributes("C:\\NightlyBuild", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```